# Overloading operator= as Non-Member

Tags: c++, oop, operator-overloading, encapsulation, assignment-operator

According to replies to [this](http://www.gidforums.com/t-5363.html) thread, `operator=` cannot be overloaded as a non-member function.  So, for example, the following makes the compiler very angry:

```
class MyClass
{
    // ...
};

MyClass& operator=(MyClass& Left, MyClass& Right)
{
    // ...
}
```

Why is this?  I have a container class with getters and setters, so a member function is unnecessary and it would break encapsulation.  One of the answers to the aforementioned thread said that it's to make sure the "L-value is received as its first operand," but I don't fully understand what that means.  Could someone please clarify?

Additionally, are `operator=`, `operator()`, `operator[]` and `operator->` "oddball" cases...?  Or should I implement *all* overloaded operators as member functions...?  (I know it's perfectly legal to do otherwise, but I'm looking for the better practice.)

Comment: Also see this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938036/rationale-of-enforcing-some-operators-to-be-members

Comment: I think getters/setters break encapsulation more than an assignment operator. Note: If if you do not define one your class already has an assignment operator. Try it.

Comment: Member functions don't break encapsulation; they're a part of it. The preference to create "non-member, non-friend functions" can result in simpler classes, but in the general case, exposing everything necessary to implement operator=() is more likely to weaken encapsulation than making operator=() a member.

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3933637/why-friend-function-cant-be-used-for-overloading-assignment-operator

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your class doesn't have an assignment operator (as a member), the compiler generates one by default, just like it generates a copy constructor if you don't provide one.

Therefore it will be "angry" if you try to define a non-member assignment operator later. There will then be two!

Comment: The rule could simply be changed to try to find a non-member one first.

Comment: @GMan What if the non-member operator is in another translation unit? An ODR violation?

Comment: @GMan: So, how would you make a non-ODR-violating definition then? You always have to *define* it is *some* translation unit.

Comment: @GMan (first comment) The rule is applied to the class definition, when the definition is seen.  C++ doesn't like the idea that a class can have two different definitions at different places in the same source file.

Comment: @Andrey @James: Sorry, I deleted my answer, forgot about the comments. I don't support any claims I made in this question any longer. :) Andrey answered it in another question, linked above.

Comment: "_What if the non-member operator is in another translation unit?_" Yes, what should happen according to you? "_An ODR violation?_" Why? Why would assignment mean the same thing in two TU?

Answer (score 2):

> Why is this?

Unless you declare one, the compiler declares an `operator=` in your class with signature `operator= (C&, C&)` or `operator= (C&, const C&)`.

If you were allowed to overload assignment, most uses would be ambiguous.

Then you would likely lobby for **additional rules** to either:

- pretend there is no compiler declared `operator=` if a user declared one is visible, as if the non-member `operator=` hides the member `operator=`
- make your user declared assignment a better match during overloading.

Both choices would complicate rules that are already extremely complicated, adding a special case just for `operator=`.

Few people want to go there.

And also **you haven't exposed a legitimate use for this feature.**

Or, *any* reasonable use at all.

The C++ rules are only made even more complicated when some reasonable use-case can be showed.