# C++ error C2801: 'operator =' must be a non-static member

Tags: c++, class, templates, overloading, operator-keyword

I am trying to overload the `operator=` in a template class.

I have this template class:

```
template <class T>
class Matrice
{
    T m,n;
public:
    template <class V>
    friend Matrice<V>& operator=(const Matrice<V> &);
};

template <class T>
Matrice<T>& Matrice<T>::operator=(const Matrice<T> &M)
{
    /*...*/
    return *this;
}
```

and I also tried:

```
template <class T>
class Matrice
{
    T m,n;
public:
    template <class V>
    Matrice<V>& operator=(Matrice<V> &);
};

template <class T>
Matrice<T>& operator=(Matrice<T> &M)
{
    /*...*/
    return *this;
}
```

but I still get this error:

```
error C2801: 'operator =' must be a non-static member
```

Comment: Your second example fixes the `friend` issue, but there's no resolution.

Comment: Did you read the error message?

Comment: @Griwes Can't improve it when no one anwsers my questions right

Comment: You can't change the type of your class. Your class is of type `Matrice<T>`, and whatever you do in your assignment method it will not change to `Matrice<V>`. Maybe using templates here is not the right thing to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> error C2801: 'operator =' must be a non-static **member**

The bolded word is key here. `friend` is not a member; it's a friend. Remove that `friend` keyword and treat `operator=` as member:

The syntactically proper version is:

```
template <class T>
class Matrice
{
    T m,n;
public:
    template <class V>
    Matrice<V>& operator=(const Matrice<V> &);
};

template <class T>
template <class V>
Matrice<V>& Matrice<T>::operator=(const Matrice<V> &M)
{
    /*...*/
    return *this;
}
```

Although I think that it's wrong to use that `template <class V>` there; the *sematically* proper version would be

```
template <class T>
class Matrice
{
    T m,n;
public:
    Matrice<T>& operator=(const Matrice<T> &);
};

template <class T>
Matrice<T>& Matrice<T>::operator=(const Matrice<T> &M)
{
    /*...*/
    return *this;
}
```

Explanation: you don't generally want to **assign** `Type<V>` to `Type<T>` in this way; if you have to, then it is probably sign of bad design.

Comment: With your example i get this error message: `error C2244: 'Matrice<T>::operator =' : unable to match function definition to an existing declaration`

Comment: @RevoltEr, nah, just noticed it. Let me fix it.

Comment: Bojan Komazec's solution looks simpler; should I use his or yours? Or both do the same thing?

Comment: @RevoltEr, Bojan's answer is same as my second snippet, that eliminates second template parameter, that doesn't really make sense when used in the original way.

Comment: In your second snippet you have `Matrice<V> &` instead of `Matrice<T> &`

Comment: @RevoltEr, ups, sorry, typo that was. Fixed now.

Comment: Explain to me how you return a `Matrice<V>` from a `Matrice<T>` by saying `return *this;`

Comment: @Fozi, in case you didn't notice - I said that it's syntactically correct version, and that's true, given code from OP, as we cannot assume anything else - http://ideone.com/icA8C. And above second snippet I said that *the second snippet* is **semantically** correct, which is also true. So, where is your problem now?

Comment: @Fozi, as code from original post obviously isn't full code, how safe is it to assume that there is no `template<typename V> operator Matrice<V>()` somewhere?

Comment: For one, because you return a reference. The second reason is that if you create a copy you would not actually change the state of the object you are trying to assign to. But yes, theoretically you could have a valid implementation that compiles an maybe even does something sensible.

Comment: @Fozi, good point about the reference; anyway, the code in given form can be compiled, that's why I wrote that it's **syntactically** correct.

Answer (score 3):

The standard says

> **12.8 Copying and moving class objects** [class.copy]
>
> ...
>
> *17* A user-declared copy assignment operator `X::operator=` is a non-static non-template member function of class X with exactly one parameter of type X, X&, const X&, volatile X& or const volatile X&.

A friend function doesn't fulfill these requirements. It must be a member function.

---

To address the comments that this is just "plain" assignment, not copy assignment, let's add another quote from the standard:

> **13.5.3 Assignment** [over.ass]
>
> An assignment operator shall be implemented by a non-static member function with exactly one parameter.

In standardese, "shall" doesn't leave any options to do anything else.

Comment: An operator = must not necessarily be the copy assignment operator.

Comment: @Fozi, in what case `X::operator=()` isn't the copy assignment operator? Note: OP want `X::operator=()`, not `X a = X();`...

Comment: Just because it's overloading the = operator does not mean that it's copying. Pretty much any overload of the = operator that does not follow your rules above is not a copy assignment operator and will allow the compiler to create a generated one.

Answer (score 2):

You mixed *friend* and *member* declarations and definitions: in the first example you declared `operator=` as a *friend* but defined it as a class member. In the second example, you declared `operator=` as a member but tried to define it as a non-member. Your `operator=` has to be a member (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3933637/why-friend-function-cant-be-used-for-overloading-assignment-operator) why) and you can do the following:

```
template <class T>
class Matrice
{
    T m,n;
public:
    Matrice<T>& operator=(Matrice<T> &);
};

template <class T>
Matrice<T>& Matrice<T>::operator=(Matrice<T> &M)
{
    /*...*/
    return *this;
}
```