# Why can't operator= be non-member, if the original one is deleted

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm aware of questions that answer why it can't be non-member, [such as this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3933637/why-non-member-function-cant-be-used-for-overloading-assignment-operator), but I'm wondering why it still isn't allowed if `operator=` is `= delete`d. I'm not completely convinced, but wouldn't that resolve all the ambiguity problems?

Comment: A deleted function is still part of overloads.

Comment: hmm... good point. It's also kinda weird to delete a member function, then define it a different way. On the other hand, it does make at least some sense - and without extending the language, make a well defined way to do this.